# Что сильнее ест память - стандартный логгер, println, или log4j и др.?

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

В какой то статье читал про то, что логгировать все - не очень хорошая практика, т.к. логгирование ест память. В одном телеграм канале был такой пост:

```
Хорошо — Плохо

Плохо
System.out.println("My Message");

Хорошо
logger.info("My Message");
```

И у меня вопрос - действительно ли логгирование(из `util`) потребляет больше памяти чем `println`? И если сравнивать `log4j`(и другие бибилиотеки), стандартное логгирование и `println` - что потребляет больше памяти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вопрос исключительно про память, то выигрывает метод `System.out.println` он ее не потребляет вообще.

Если случай чуть сложнее и сравнивать нужно

```
 logger.debug("par1 = {} par2 = {}", par1, par2);
```

и

```
System.out.println("par1 = " + par1 + " par2 = " + par2);
```

То ситуация сложнее.

Логгер выигрывает в случае если он ничего не печатает.

Comment: А если они печатают одинаковые элементы? и не debug а info?

Comment: Если результат на выходе одинаковый, то логер потребляет не меньше памяти.